# Пропал звук в Xubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu, pulseaudio

Очень давно пользуюсь Xubuntu и никогда подобных багов не наблюдал, но с недавних пор при включении или перезагрузке компьютера стал отсутствовать звук.

Открывая меню настроек pulseaudio я вижу, что звук поступает в некое устройство "HDMI/Display port" и никакие другие устройства недоступны:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я выключаю колонки и вставляю снова, в любой из разъёмов (их у меня всего два) ничего не меняется, но как только я меняю колонки на наушники или наоборот, то устройство "HDMI/Display port" исчезает, вместо него появляются настоящие устройства и начинает воспроизводиться звук:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что после каждой перезагрузки теперь приходится дёргать шнуры и очень странно, что этот фантомный порт считается настоящим девайсом, не виртуальным.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется разобрался! При смене устройства автоматически меняется профиль настроек (последняя вкладка). Если указать его вручную (в моём случае это "Аналоговый стерео дуплекс"), то проблема вроде как решается.